# problems with multiDiv in paleotree package

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

I am trying to use the package paleotree to build LTT plots, but I get the following error when I try to input my trees.

```
a=read.tree(file.choose()) # to choose newick/nexus file
multiDiv(a)
```

Error in multiDiv(a) : Data of Unknown Type

Does paleotools only take objects of class 'multiphylo' ? I converted the imput tree to class multiphylo, but it still gives the same error. Can anyone suggest how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of package `paleotree`. I think what is going on here is that you are passing a single tree to `multiDiv`, which is setup for analyzing lists of objects, each of which are converted to a diversity curve. You probably want `phyloDiv()` instead. I can't be certain without know more about your data.